# Playwright - select random option

Tags: playwright

I want the test to filter the results randomly.
Choosing option:

```py
selects = section.locator("select")
number_of_selects = selects.count()
chosen_number = randint(1, number_of_selects)
chosen_select = elements.nth(chosen_number - 1)

options = chosen_select.locator("option")
number_of_options = options.count()
chosen_number = randint(1, number_of_options)
chosen_option = options.nth(chosen_number - 1)
```

When I try to select the chosen option, I get a problem:

I've tried with `text_content()`...

```py
select_name = chosen_select.text_content()
option_name = chosen_option.text_content()

page.locator(select_name).select_option(label=option_name)
```

...with `get_attribute()`...

```py
chosen_value = chosen_option.get_attribute("value")

page.locator(select_name).select_option(chosen_value)
```

...but i get an error every time:

> Locator.select_option(-YesNo)
> waiting for selector "-YesNo"

HTML:

```html
<selecet id="listYN">
   <option value=-1>"-"</option>
   <option value=YES>"Yes"</option>
   <option value=NO>"No"</option>
</select>
```

How can I **randomly** select options?

Comment: What error you are getting with the first option ?

Comment: Locator.select_option(-YesNo)
waiting for selector "-YesNo"

Answer (score 0):

after a few hours, I found the answer:

```
chosen_select.select_option(chosen_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Came this way looking for an answer. Thought I'd share some learning. Given that I have a select which id is 'countries' then this (at time of writing) works for me...

```
await page.selectOption("#countries", {index: randomInt(await page.locator("#countries").evaluate(obj => obj.length)});
```

If you want to access the selected option's value or content then you need to resort to a little bit of evaluated Javascript...

```
const selectedValue = await page.locator(“#countries”).evaluate(sel => sel.options[sel.options.selectedIndex].textContent);
const selectedText = await page.locator(“#countries”).evaluate(sel => sel.options[sel.options.selectedIndex].value);
```

Luck.

Answer (score 0):

### Simple Example:

#### 1). First Locate the Dropdown Element:

```
const dropdown = await page.locator('select')
```

#### 2). Count the Number of Options:

```
const numberOfOptions = await dropdown.locator('option').count()
```

#### 3).Generate a Random Index:

```
const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfOptions)
```

#### 4). Select the Option:

```
await dropdown.selectOption({ index: randomIndex })
```

Reference:

https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-select-option
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/29127#issuecomment-1906902977